# SQL Database refactoring tool

Tags: sql, database, refactoring

Does anyone know of a tool that exists to refactor SQL database tables?

I want a tool which will allow me to alter a table (add,remove columns or change datatype etc) without dropping the table. I also want to be able to keep the existing data in the table and maybe add defaults to any new columns (in the case of NOT NULL columns).

Is there anything out there that would help with refactoring tables?

Comment: Any particular "brand" of database, or just databases in general?

Comment: for sql server, oracle, sybase ase, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management Studio for Microsoft SQL Server lets you edit the table layout. It will of course recreate the table in the background if needed and copy the data, but it does that automatically.

Comment: For SQL Server 2008 please. I have found if I try to edit a table in Manamement Studio it sometimes advises that I need to drop the database.

Comment: This happens when adding not nullable columns. I want to be able to add columns and enter default data also for not nullable columns.

Comment: There is a setting in Management Studio that only allows changes that doesn't recreate the table, which may be on by default. If you turn off this setting, you can edit your table.

Comment: Still get the message after turning "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation" option off.

Comment: Got it. Just need to add a default value into the new col. Looks to work so will have a play. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/) works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

check out http://www.red-gate.com. They have a great suite of tools.

Comment: Was looking at redgate but wanted to get feedback before paying for it.

Answer (score 0):

i would use [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593), another one i can recommend is [OmegaSync](http://www.spectralcore.com/omegasync/)